# why cant my checkbox be checked by id

Tags: javascript, checkbox

my checkbox does not want to check by id, it only allows it to be checked by name. Here is the code:

```
function selectAll(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('id');
    var button = document.getElementById('toggle');
    if(button.value == ''){
        for (var i in checkboxes){
            checkboxes[i].checked = 'FALSE';
        }
        button.value = 'X'
    } else {
        for (var i in checkboxes){
            checkboxes[i].checked = '';
        }
        button.value = '';
    }
}
```

Why cant my checkbox be checked by id?

Comment: You can use `if(button.value)` instead of `if(button.value != '')`. And note that a using `for..in` loop to iterate a `NodeList` is a bad idea (see [how to do it properly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Example)).

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('id');` will get all elements where `name="id"`. Is that really what you intend? Also, you shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate over a `NodeList`.

Comment: So what is working for you, and what isn't?

Answer (score 2):

use `true` and `false`, not `''` and `'FALSE'`

```
checkboxes[i].checked = false;
```

also make sure you have a checkbox with the id your looking for

Comment: are you trying to check or uncheck? if checking set to `true`

Comment: verify that `checkboxes.length > 0`